# Display a payment link for custom order statuses in Woocommerce email notifications

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement, woocommerce, orders

I've been struggling for a while to get this to work. I need to show this payment link in my woocommerce emails, but only on certain (custom) order statuses. How is it done? Thanks :)

```
    printf(
    wp_kses(
        /* translators: %1s item is the name of the site, %2s is a html link */
        __( '%2$s', 'woocommerce' ),
        array(
            'a' => array(
                'href' => array(),
            ),
        )
    ),
    esc_html( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ),
    '<a href="' . esc_url( $order->get_checkout_payment_url() ) . '">' . esc_html__( 'Click here to pay for this order', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>'
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will use the `WC_Order` method `get_status()` in something like:

```
if( in_array( $order->get_status(), array( 'custom-one', 'custom-two') ) ) {
    printf( wp_kses(
        /* translators: %1s item is the name of the site, %2s is a html link */
        __( '%2$s', 'woocommerce' ), array(
            'a' => array(
                'href' => array(),
            ),
        ) ),
        esc_html( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) 
    ), '<a href="' . esc_url( $order->get_checkout_payment_url() ) . '">' .
    esc_html__( 'Click here to pay for this order', 'woocommerce' ) . '</a>' );
}
```

It should works *(where you will  replace `custom-one` and `custom-two` by your custom statuses slugs)*

Comment: Hi! Thank you for taking the time to help me. I am not able to get this to work for some reason. Just the link alone works, but as soon as I start adding the if statement, I start getting errors. I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know what. 

The logs say I have on error a few lines above where I'm working, but I don't understand why. I haven't touched that part.. It's still the original template...


Here's the error: 2019-02-15T14:15:23-05:00 CRITICAL syntax error, unexpected 'IS' (T_STRING)

Comment: You're right (again!). I think you helped me the other day as well. Thanks again :)